# How to use distinct in third column

Tags: sql, distinct

I want to run the query

```
select first_name, last_name, distinct salary from employees
```

But it throws an error. While if I use this `select distinct salary, first_name, last_name from employees` it runs.

I want o/p in the form of first column should be first_name then last_name then distinct salary.

Comment: DISTINCT belongs to the SELECT keyword, i.e. it's SELECT DISTINCT. And it works on the whole selected rows.

Comment: What result do you expect if several different persons have the same salary?

Comment: What does this even mean? Can you post some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: shouldn't... shouldn't salary already be distinct for an individual?

Comment: Hello Mayur welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
 SELECT Salary, First_Name, Last_Name 
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Salary
```

the above should return a list of first_name and last_name of people who share the same salary.

If your data set contains duplicate rows you may want to do this to get rid of duplicate rows:

```
WITH salaries
     AS ( SELECT DISTINCT Salary,
                          First_Name,
                          Last_Name
          FROM table_name )
     SELECT Salary,
            First_Name,
            Last_Name
     FROM salaries
     GROUP BY Salary;
```

Comment: And this is for which dbms? (No dbms specified, so ANSI SQL is assumed...)

Comment: this is if you are running MS SQL Server

Comment: yep. the above query is just a group by. and the one below leverages Common Table Expressions

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." Here you GROUP BY Salary, but also select First_Name, Last_Name.

Comment: oh my bad jarlh... I see what you were pointing out. You will need to do this:

SELECT Salary, MAX(First_Name), MAX(Last_Name) 
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Salary

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick, you should insert first to temp table where you distinct the `salary`, then after that , you can now select the data in your temp table with your desired arrangement of columns.

```
    select distinct salary, first_name, last_name * into #temp from employees
```

Then after the distinct, you can now do what you want in the second query without the `distinct`.

```
    select first_name, last_name, salary from #temp
```

Comment: And this is for which dbms? (No dbms specified, so ANSI SQL is assumed...)

Comment: @jarlh assuming that using SQL Server.. yup `select distinct` works on the whole rows.. i created the trick so that he wont encounter an error :)

Comment: But isn't what you do the same as select distinct salary, first_name, last_name from employees?